# Signature overload: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true'

Tags: typescript

I am wondering why typescript is complaining about a boolean parameter which is not assignable to my lib function:

lib:

```
public async getAccessToken(scopes?: string[]): Promise<string | null>;
public async getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded: false): Promise<string | null>;
public async getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded: true): Promise<AccessToken | null>;
public async getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded?: boolean) {
  ...
}
```

declaration file:

```
getAccessToken(scopes?: string[]): Promise<string | null>;
getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded: false): Promise<string | null>;
getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded: true): Promise<AccessToken | null>;
```

app:

```
public async getAccessToken(decoded = false) {
  // TS2345: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true'.
  return authClient.getAccessToken(undefined, decoded);
}
```

I have tried several variants of the signature overload but none seems to work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke `getAccessToken` with `decoded` of type `boolean`, but you only have overloads defined, that can handle *either* `true` or `false`. 
The function implementation of `getAccessToken` doesn't count as overload.

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) - it is *not* possible to pass a union function argument type for `decoded` (`boolean` can be seen as `true | false`) and let TS resolve the return type as union of all possible overloads.

So what is a solution here? Define an additional overload, that can handle `decoded:boolean`:

```
// ... your other overloads ...
// in addition, add overload down under
public async getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded: boolean): Promise<string | AccessToken | null>;
// impl
public async getAccessToken(scopes: string[] | undefined, decoded?: boolean) {...}
```

Alternatively invoke `getAccessToken` directly with `true` or `false` type.

[Sample Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=48&pln=15&pc=55#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxnCBnJAVA9gawgOygXigG8oA3ALigEMcQoBfAWACgW4AbKlKAMXXWIsowqGACuAI3YBLONSQgccgOYRg8RCgzYcACiRx0kJAH5KSYACdpOZQG0AugEpKABUvoAttKQQAPBbWtlAAPlA4YuzsAHwA3EIi4lKy8ooqahrIaFi4%20obG5lY29g6hUGI4ACYQAGY2EJUANFDVhtWVlDVU7L4uUO5ePv6BxWURUXEJwkkyclxpUKrqCFnauQZGyIVBJWUV1XU4Dc2t6O2UVmIQfQPevn6ZWjl4YeMx8cwiopKzqUqLGRWTx0eU2SG2xUceyqtXqTRaEDaDUoEn47AgNBuHjuwyKwTCj2yOjGkXeU2%20yTmCn%20S0Jaz0GwKUBGtihYX2sKO8NO7TMUFR6HRmMEny%20IksajEljwtyGADoJUhBaQILoAERq%20TUWhOclMZj6lg1CpwYDSdB4DjSXDAXQ8hoEKBdHrXEVfAD07qgqAAygAmADMABYAKyUGCWZRiTw2qDoGpQUCQKAAcgFQpwKagPnC6GA8iQ0mUOCoUmgwAEYColioMeAEEscYTSegKcuEBTcvJEuAUrwRwA7rx%20LonHLaUCibkOYdjgikZUnB96EA)